# Multiple GETDATE() in Redshift

Tags: redshift

I have a long (and long running, ~30min depending on load) query. It has multiple statements UNION'ed together. Most of the statements are using the `GETDATE` function[1].

1. Is the function executed once or multiple times?
2. If multiple times, would putting it into a `WITH` statement and then `SELECT timestamp FROM <WITH statement>` making it getting executed only once?

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html

Comment: The overhead of calling getdate() is so small that you shouldn't worry

Comment: It's not the overhead I am concerned about, but whether I am getting the same timestamp in all subqueries or not. The documentation doesn't say anything about it.